# OData enum mapping as int not working in 8.2.3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0, odata-v4

In .Net Core 2.2 project we used Odata 7.1.0 version. We mapped Enum in model separately with NotMapped property then in model builder we mapped it with StructuralTypeConfiguration it is working fine It is returning ReportStatusId as int and ReportStatus as string value.

```
Model
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("ReportStatus", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public EnumReportStatus ReportStatus { get; set; } = EnumReportStatus.Draft;
        [NotMapped]
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("ReportStatusId", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public int ReportStatusId
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)ReportStatus;
            }
        }

Model Builder 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
StructuralTypeConfiguration<ReportingItem> rpItem = builder.EntitySet<ReportingItem>(nameof(ReportingItem)).EntityType.Count().Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand();
            rpItem.Property(g => g.ReportStatusId);
```

Now we are migrating to .NET6 we have upgraded Odata to 8.2.3. Now above code is not working.
Are we missing anything here  ??

Comment: Make sure you do a clean build to remove all intermediate obj files.  Also make sure you use the main branch as described here : https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData#1-introduction. Also make sure you have the correct dependencies : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/#dependencies-body-tab

Comment: @jdweng I have checked these in the project dependencies are already exist as per their config in NugetT.  I think i don't need to switch to main branch as i am using Nuget Package.

Comment: The first link says "Be noted: Switch to use "main" as default branch. 1/6/2022"

Comment: What isn't working?  Is the connection completing.  Do you get a response with a status?  Updating request two step authentication which may be cause of issue.

Comment: @jdweng We did not cloned the OData repository, We are consuming **Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData** package from NuGet

Comment: Did you try 8.2.2?  What isn't working?  See : https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/releases

Comment: @jdweng Yes I tried it and 8.2.2 is deprecated version

Comment: When there is a bug in latest version of a library you sometimes have to go back to an older version until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Finally found the solution with some and error. You just need to do one change in EDM model binding. Remove `Count().Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand()` from EDM binding. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution with some and error. You just need to do one change in EDM model binding.
Remove `Count().Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand()` from EDM binding. It worked for me.